# Subsetting a vector base on another vector

Tags: r

I have 2 input vectors, `iv1` and `iv2`, as shown below. I would like to separate the elements of the second vector according to elements of the first. It works like this: The values in `iv2` between the first 2 values of `iv1` are stored in `ov1`, the values in `iv2` between the second and third values of `iv1` are stored in `ov2`, and so on. Note: The values in `iv1` and `iv2` are already in ascending order. Any thoughts please?

Input:

```
iv1 <- c(100, 200, 300, 400, 435)
iv2 <- c(60, 120, 140, 160, 180, 230, 250, 255, 265, 270, 295, 340, 355, 401, 422, 424, 430)
```

Desired output:

```
ov1 = c(120, 140, 160, 180)
ov2 = c(230, 250, 255, 265, 270, 295)
ov3 = c(340, 355)
ov4 = c(401, 422, 424, 430)
```

Comment: `split(iv2, cut(iv2, breaks = iv1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @RonakShah suggested, the most efficient way in this case may be this:

```
split(iv2, cut(iv2, breaks = iv1,labels = paste0('ov',1:4)))
```

Output:

```
$ov1
[1] 120 140 160 180

$ov2
[1] 230 250 255 265 270 295

$ov3
[1] 340 355

$ov4
[1] 401 422 424 430
```

Comment: Perfect! The output looks good. But I guess the values for each ov are not stored as arrays. I try to view ov1 and I get "Error: object 'ov1' not found". Any suggestions please?

Comment: @user8556385 - Glad it helped. Yes, the values are stored in a list here, not an array. So if we store the above in "x" (i.e. x<-split...), then we can access the individual list elements by name (e.g. ov1) like this: x[['ov1']]

Comment: Got it. Thank you!